# Canon Registry Keys Remain after Uninstallation

Tags: windows-7, printer, windows-registry, mysql

I have a Canon printer but have found that with it installed I can't correctly install MySQL (there are threads about this problem).  So I uninstalled the Canon files, reinstalled MySQL and found that the MySQL installation is creating Canon directories.  So I searched the registry and there are keys for Canon still there.

I worry about deleting every key that say Canon when I don't really understand what I'm deleting. Can anyone suggest a way to get the Canon registry keys removed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up searching the registry for the string 'webprint'.  There were a few entries and I deleted them, reinstalled MySQL and the directory structure looks correct.  I then reinstalled the Cannon files (though I did not install WebPrint) and everything is working fine at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I use Revo Uninstaller (not sure who makes it and I'm away from my rig, sorry) when removing Windows programs as it searches for both leftover configuration files and registry keys in addition to the standard uninstall process, leaving your machine a bit cleaner than just normally uninstalling.

But, at this point that is too late to help, which is where CCleaner (from Piriform, would link to it but I'm on my phone) can help you. It searches for dead registry keys and can remove them, and can perform a number of useful maintenance tasks as well.

Comment: Thanks for those two suggestions.  I was about to reinstall Cannon's files and use Revo to uninstall and decided to search the registry for 'webprint' and there were a few references.  I deleted them (with a bit of trepidation) but Windows seems to be working ok, MySQL seems to be installed correctly and when I reinstalled the printer (without the WebPrint bs) it works fine.  Painful that uninstall doesn't mean clean your tracks.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I rather like these sites to get info myself, so I'm always glad to help others in turn.

Comment: If my answer is satisfactory please accept it, else write your own answer and accept it for the benefit of those with the same or similar problem.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your help. I will download CCleaner later today and see if I missed any entries.